# FastReport preview not showing all pages

Tags: delphi, preview, fastreport

I'm using FastReport 4.7.31 in Turbo Delphi Pro.

The following procedure processes the data stored in several dated files depending on user input.

```
    procedure TfrmMain.MyReportPrint;
var  MDate : Tdate;
     S, myfile : string;
     firstone: boolean;
//   Date1, Date2 & ShowPreview are global variables set via a dialog box     
begin
   firstone := true;
   MDate := Date1;
   while MDate < IncDay(Date2, 1)  do
   begin
      DateTimeToString(S,'yyyymmdd',MDate);
      myfile := 'm' + S + '.dbf';
      if FileExists(DataPath + '\' + myfile) then
      begin
         tblPS.Close;
         tblPS.TableName := myfile;
         frxMyReport.PrepareReport(firstone);
         firstone := false;
      end;
      MDate := IncDay(MDate, 1);
   end;
   if ShowPreview then frxMyReport.ShowReport else frxMyReport.Print;
end;
```

frxMyReport.Print prints **all** the pages.

frxMyReport.ShowReport shows **only the last page** prepared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ShowReport` method takes an optional parameter `ClearLastReport`, and its default value is **true**. Whether it's true or false, `ShowReport` prepares the report before displaying it, so in your code, you're discarding everything you've already prepared and then re-preparing the report using the most recently assigned table settings. If the only change you were to make to your code would be to pass `False` to `ShowReport`, then you'd find that the preview showed all your pages, but repeated the last page.

In contrast to `ShowReport`, the `Print` method does *not* prepare the report. It only prints what has already been prepared. You want `ShowPreparedReport` for your preview, not `ShowReport`. See section 1.9 of the *FastReport Programmer's Manual*.